# Summarize dataframe with start and end times in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Here is a sample of my df:

```
   structure(list(press_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
    start_time = c(164429106370978, 164429106370978, 164429411618824, 
    164429411618824, 164429837271939, 164429837271939, 164430399454284, 
    164430399454284), end_time = c(164429182443824, 164429182443824, 
    164429512525747, 164429512525747, 164429903243169, 164429903243169, 
    164430465927554, 164430465927554), timestamp = c(164429140697138, 
    164429175921880, 164429440899844, 164429440899844, 164429867184830, 
    164429891199391, 164430427558256, 164430433561155), acc_x = c(3.1053743, 
    2.9904492, 5.889916, 5.889916, 5.808511, 5.36557, 3.545921, 
    3.4788814), acc_y = c(8.406299, 8.12138, 8.600235, 8.600235, 
    7.920261, 7.922655, 7.9346266, 7.972935), acc_z = c(4.577853, 
    4.0894213, 0.35435268, 0.35435268, -0.21309046, 0.46927786, 
    4.005622, 4.4198313), grav_x = c(3.931084, 4.0214577, 4.7844357, 
    4.7844357, 5.6572776, 5.65053, 3.9938855, 3.9938855), grav_y = c(8.318872, 
    8.281514, 8.21449, 8.21449, 7.94851, 7.9495893, 8.027369, 
    8.027369), grav_z = c(3.393116, 3.3785365, 2.408623, 2.408623, 
    0.99327636, 1.0226398, 3.9724596, 3.9724596), gyro_x = c(-0.35906965, 
    0.099690154, 0.06792516, 0.04532315, -0.05546962, -0.06524346, 
    -0.2967614, -0.32180685), gyro_y = c(0.15843217, -0.48053285, 
    -0.2196934, -0.21175216, 0.1895863, 0.37467846, 0.12239113, 
    0.04847643), gyro_z = c(-0.042139318, 0.39585108, 0.12523776, 
    0.11240959, -0.05863268, 0.042770952, 0.047047008, 0.097137965
    ), acc_mag = c(10.0630984547559, 9.5719886173707, 10.4297995361418, 
    10.4297995361418, 9.82419166595324, 9.58008483176486, 9.56958006531909, 
    9.75731607717771), acc_mag_max = c(10.4656808698978, 10.4656808698978, 
    10.5978974240054, 10.5978974240054, 10.2717799984467, 10.2717799984467, 
    10.0054693945119, 10.0054693945119), acc_mag_min = c(9.55048847884876, 
    9.55048847884876, 9.45791784630329, 9.45791784630329, 9.58008483176486, 
    9.58008483176486, 9.49389444102469, 9.49389444102469), acc_mag_avg = c(9.9181794947982, 
    9.9181794947982, 9.82876220923978, 9.82876220923978, 9.89351246166363, 
    9.89351246166363, 9.77034322149792, 9.77034322149792), vel_ang_mag = c(0.394724572535758, 
    0.630514095219792, 0.261846355511019, 0.243985821544114, 
    0.206052505577139, 0.382714007838398, 0.324438496782347, 
    0.339625377757329), vel_ang_mag_max = c(0.665292823798622, 
    0.665292823798622, 1.00730683166191, 1.00730683166191, 0.561349818527019, 
    0.561349818527019, 0.445252333070234, 0.445252333070234), 
    vel_ang_mag_min = c(0.212944405199931, 0.212944405199931, 
    0.18680382123856, 0.18680382123856, 0.111795327479332, 0.111795327479332, 
    0.258342546774667, 0.258342546774667), vel_ang_mag_avg = c(0.440700089033948, 
    0.440700089033948, 0.405484992593493, 0.405484992593493, 
    0.284553957549617, 0.284553957549617, 0.348811700631375, 
    0.348811700631375)), .Names = c("press_id", "start_time", 
"end_time", "timestamp", "acc_x", "acc_y", "acc_z", "grav_x", 
"grav_y", "grav_z", "gyro_x", "gyro_y", "gyro_z", "acc_mag", 
"acc_mag_max", "acc_mag_min", "acc_mag_avg", "vel_ang_mag", "vel_ang_mag_max", 
"vel_ang_mag_min", "vel_ang_mag_avg"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "press_id", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:1, 2:3, 4:5, 6:7), group_sizes = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
    press_id = 1:4), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame", vars = "press_id", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:1, 2:3, 4:5, 6:7), group_sizes = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
    press_id = 1:4), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame", vars = "press_id", drop = TRUE, .Names = "press_id"), .Names = "press_id"))
```

And I am trying to summarize it in the following way where the last columns(the blank are filled with their appropriate values from above dataframe):

```
press_id  time_state  time_state_val    acc_mag acc_mag_max acc_mag_min acc_mag_avg vel_ang_mag vel_ang_mag_max vel_ang_mag_min vel_ang_mag_avg
1         start_time  164429106370978    
1         end_time    164429182443824
2         start_time  164429411618824
2         end_time    164429512525747
3         start_time  164429837271939
3         end_time    164429903243169
4         start_time  164430399454284
4         end_time    164430427558256
```

Please advise how can I transform it to be like expected result.
I am trying to do this with combination of `tidyr` `gather` and `dplyr` but I don't get the structure I need.

Comment: Each id has 2 start and 2 end how you would like to reduce them to 1 start and 1 end.

Comment: How do you get the `*_mag` from the `*_x`, `*_y`, `*_z` values? You need to provide more details as to how the different summary statistics are calculated.

Comment: @MauritsEvers it's the regular Euclid's magnitude sqrt(sum(*_x^2, *_y^2, *_z^2). It's not part of the question. My question fits exactly to A. Suliman's answer.

Comment: @steves unfortunately your question is not very clear. But you’ve got your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  
df1 <- df[,1:6]
df1 %>% mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
        gather(time_state , time_state_val, -press_id, -row,-timestamp:-acc_y) %>%
        arrange(press_id, row) %>% 
        select(press_id, time_state, time_state_val, everything(),-row)
```

Comment: Why do I need row = row_number?

Comment: @steves to make sure each start follows by end in the final output when using `arrange` with `press_id`